# Implementation of congruence in java

Tags: java, modulo

Is there a way to calculate if an integer is congruent with the expression 17 modulo 5 in java. The expression could be any variation of the x modulo y.  Any ideas on how to make a method to check for this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can calculate the remainder of a division by five as `x % 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's remainder operator `%`. If `a` and `b` are both positive, `a % b` equals the `a mod b`.

However, the (mathematical) meaning of modulo is a bit different. If `b` is positive, `a % b` has the same sign a `a`. Thus `-3 % 10 = -3`, while `-3 mod 10 = 7`. To calculate the modulo, you can use

```
int result = a % b;
if (result < 0 && b > 0) {
    result += b;
}
```

or as a single expression:

```
((a % b) + b) % b
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is ;)

```
% : (Modulus)

Divides left-hand operand by right-hand operand and returns remainder.
```

If `A=10 and B=20 : B % A` will give 0

So a test like : `if(a%b==0)` will surely help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If for example you want to make a conditional statement like x an integer :

`x = 1[4]`

or x congruent to 1 modulo 4

simply write :

```
if ((x % 4)==1) {
    ...
}
```

You can apply this in a multitude of other applications.